# Android Studio - Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect after upgrade to 2.1.2 version

Tags: android, android-keystore

Recently I upgraded Android Studio to latest stable version 2.1.2 (Win 10, Java 1.8.0_45) and problem I'm experiencing now when I try to build signed application is

```
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

If I try to list keystore got this

```
$ keytool -list -keystore my-keystore.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

my-keystore, Jul 1, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):     2E:20:24:85:FF:BD:5A:D2:07:52:75:90:87:85:FD:C7:FB:1A:DA:71
```

but on android studio when I want to load key get

> cannot load key store...

is there to somehow solve this kind of issue? I would rather do some fix than create new keystore file and change app on play.

Comment: Key was generated in android studio 1.5.0 and it worked ok.

Comment: Im having a similiar problem. updated android studio yesterday and my keystore,keystore password, alias & key password all disapeared. I managed to find my keystore. I had the key store password and key password written down and think that my alias was actually written in the keystore in the first line

Comment: i luckly had a old version of android studio 2.0, i opened that and as well I was extremely lucky to be able to recover the keystore and credentials. created a signed apk no problem and uploaded a beta to play, appears to be an issue with the new update! DEADLY issue with that update as if I hadnt been able to recover keystore + credentials it would of been bye bye to app!.

Comment: Have you found a resolution to this problem?  I am facing the same in Android Studio 2.2.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky basically I reverted it to 1.5.9 version and founded old password and yeah all is good as before.